# retrieving number of observations with non missing values

Tags: r, panel

I would like to compute the number of observations (Persons in my following example) that have non-missing values.

```
unbal <- data.frame(PERSON=c(rep('Frank',5),rep('Tony',5),rep('Edward',5)), YEAR=c(2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005), Y=c(21,22,23,24,25,5,6,NA,7,8,31,32,33,34,35), X=c(1:15))
unbal

   PERSON YEAR  Y  X
1   Frank 2001 21  1
2   Frank 2002 22  2
3   Frank 2003 23  3
4   Frank 2004 24  4
5   Frank 2005 25  5
6    Tony 2001  5  6
7    Tony 2002  6  7
8    Tony 2003 NA  8
9    Tony 2004  7  9
10   Tony 2005  8 10
11 Edward 2001 31 11
12 Edward 2002 32 12
13 Edward 2003 33 13
14 Edward 2004 34 14
15 Edward 2005 35 15
```

In this case will be 2, since only two persons (Frank and Edward) have all the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try that:

```
length(unique(unbal$PERSON[!unbal$PERSON%in%unbal[!complete.cases(unbal),1]]))
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 4):

One way via base R,

```
sapply(split(unbal, unbal$PERSON), function(i) all(complete.cases(i)))
#Edward  Frank   Tony 
#  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
```

You can do this to extract,

```
ind <- sapply(split(unbal, unbal$PERSON), function(i) all(complete.cases(i)))
names(ind)[ind]
#[1] "Edward" "Frank" 

#or for the length
length(ind[ind])
#[1] 2
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Sotos, it is what I was looking for. How could I count the observations with TRUE values?

Comment: @AndresAzqueta If you want the number of TRUE observations per person you could use this: `colSums(sapply(split(unbal, unbal$PERSON), function(i) complete.cases(i)))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(unbal)[, .(ind = all(complete.cases(.SD))), PERSON]
```

and if we need the 'PERSON', just extract it

```
setDT(unbal)[, .(ind = all(complete.cases(.SD))), PERSON][(ind), PERSON]
#[1] Frank  Edward
```

and if we need the total number

```
setDT(unbal)[, .(ind = all(complete.cases(.SD))), PERSON][, sum(ind)]
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this :

```
cp = 0

for (i in unique(unbal$PERSON)){
  new_data = unbal[which(unbal$PERSON == i),]
  if (anyNA(new_data) == FALSE){
    cp = cp+1
  }else{
    cp = cp
  }
}

cp
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anyNA`, which will can operate on data.frames together with `by`. Prepending the `!` operator negates the results to return the desired values.

Using `by`,

```
!by(unbal, unbal["PERSON"], FUN=anyNA)
PERSON: Edward
[1] TRUE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
PERSON: Frank
[1] TRUE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
PERSON: Tony
[1] FALSE
```

or to return a named vector, wrap it in `c`.

```
!c(by(unbal, unbal["PERSON"], FUN=anyNA))
Edward  Frank   Tony 
  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
```

to calculate the number of persons with no missing values, wrap this in `sum`

```
sum(!c(by(unbal, unbal["PERSON"], FUN=anyNA)))
[1] 2
```

---

A modification of sotos's method, we can use `anyNA` like this.

```
!sapply(split(unbal, unbal$PERSON), anyNA)
Edward  Frank   Tony 
  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
```